# A is the matrix of $T$: $V \rightarrow V$ with repect to the basis H. Find the matrix B of $T$ with respect to G.

Tags: linear-algebra

A is the matrix of $T$: $V \rightarrow V$ with repect to the basis H. Find the matrix B of $T$ with respect to G.

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ , H = {$x^{2}$, $x$ , 1} and G = {$x^{2}$, $x$ , 1 , $x$ + 1, 1}

I do not know how to go about solving this! Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Make G into linearly independent basis first.

Comment: How can I do that? Can I get more help? I'm going this question as an example to solve another question on my exam.

Comment: The element $x+1$ in $G$ is just the addition of $x$ and $1$ in $G$, and $1$ is repeated in $G$. So, the new basis $G'=\{x^2,x,1\}$ which is equal to $H$. Therefore, $A=B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your $G = \{ x^2+x+1,x+1,1\}$ ? I supposed it is. Then you find the matrix $C$ of $T$ which transforms the basis $G$ to $H$. Observe $x^2+x+1 = 1x^2+1x+1(1) = [1,1,1]$, and $x+1 = 0x^2+1x+ 1(1) = [0,1,1]$, also $1= 0x^2+0x+1 = [0,0,1] \Rightarrow C = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. From this the matrix $B$ you sought is: $B = C\cdot A\cdot C^{-1}$. Can you work it out?

Comment: Yes sir I surely can! Thanks so much :)